# Do i need to push the objectid to both schemas in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Right now I'm really confused, do i need to push the objectId to both schemas or just save it in one schema?

My Schema

```
var CourseSchema = Schema({
  title: String,    
  content: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Video'}],    
});

var VideoSchema = Schema({
    ownedBy: { type: Schema.Types.String, ref: 'Course'},
    name: String
});
```

**Schema objective**

- Course can have many contents which the reference is Video, and Video
  can only owned by one Course.

Let say I want to create a new video object and then store its `ownedby` field to the a specific course objectId

Here's the code

```
app.get('/testData', function(req, res) {
   Course.findOne({ title: "Testing Course" }, function(err, course) {
       // Create a new video object
       var video = new Video();
       // store the object id into ownedby field, so that it belongs "Testing Course"
       video.ownedBy = course._id;
       video.title = newData.name;
       // save it
       video.save(function(err, vid) {
           // Is it necessarily for me to push each video object to a course's content field?
           course.content.push(vid._id);
        });   

    });

});
```

If you read the comment, then you know what I'm facing, if not then let me explain it again

1. FindOne a specific title that match the Course's collection which
   is "Testing Course"
2. create a new video's object and then store it into video's
   `ownedBy` field
3. Save the Course's object and then push each video's id to its
   content.

There is no error or whatsoever, but it is kinda redundant for me to push both object id to both schemas

The real question is, is it really needed for me to push the object id to both schemas?

Answer (score 1):

You have to update both objects with references. That means that you also need to update Course object with video _id. Currently you are using findOne() which only returns document, not updating it.

Here is code example:

```
Course.findOne({ title: "Testing Course" }, function(err, course) {
       if (err) return handleError(err);

       var video = new Video();
       video.ownedBy = course._id;
       video.title = newData.name;

       video.save(function(err, vid) {
           if (err) return handleError(err);

           course.content.push(vid._id);

           course.save(function(err) {
                if (err) return handleError(err);
           });  
       });  

    });
```

Comment: Can you show an example codes? so i can accept the answer

Comment: I added code example to may answer. Have you tried using it?